# Canvas drawing tool

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

How can I get the same effect on canvas like it's shown in the image below (source: [here](http://muro.deviantart.com/))
[image]

I try something like this [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/vU7ss/)

```
e.preventDefault();
var x =  e.pageX;
var y =  e.pageY;
if (!drawing) return
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.globalAlpha = .3;
ctx.lineJoin ='round';
ctx.lineCap = 'butt'
ctx.shadowBlur = 0;
//ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "copy";
ctx.moveTo(prev.x, prev.y);
ctx.strokeStyle = '#000';
//ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(100,0,0,0.1)';
ctx.lineTo(x, y);
ctx.lineWidth = 20;
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
prev.x = x;
prev.y = y;
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example of your attempt, instead of only one function. Have a look at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), for example.

Comment: Probably the simplest way of achieving that would be to draw circles on the mouse position in a loop. And instead of normally filled circles use a gradient with transparency that goes from blue to completely transparent. If you set the stops correctly it will be exactly the same. Try to get as far as you can with this in jsFiddle for example and if you get stuck we will help you out.

Comment: please check fiddle example I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you almost have the effect you want.

(semi-transparent, overlapping rounded strokes with opacity accumulating where they overlap).

Try changing the globalAlpha to .03 instead of .3.

Answer (score -1):

I've branched your jsFiddle, but I've amended the colour and alpha transparency a bit to get the same colour (ish) as your image :

http://jsfiddle.net/rsc8k/2/

```
ctx.globalAlpha = .1;
ctx.strokeStyle = '#337799';
```

Looks pretty similar. Note that that's all the changes I've made on your jsfiddle.

Comment: The color is not very important here.
I need the transparency(opacity) filled in equally, not like dotted.
That's not the same effect but tnx much anyway!

Comment: @David: The problem is that the canvas has no idea that the segments that make up a line, are supposed to be one line.
It just draws one segment over the other, darkening where segments of the same line overlap.

Comment: @Cerbrus I understand the reasons but I need to get the same effect like here http://muro.deviantart.com/

Comment: @David: It looks like muro is drawing the current line behind the existing content. I have no idea how they made that work, but it probably took a team of programmers to develop that application.

Comment: Downvoted. Nice. Slightly peeved. @David could you be clearer on what effect(s) it is you're after ? Perhaps state your comment above in the original question ?